# Wrong DNS for just one site on development machine

Tags: dns, tcp

www.superyoink.de is my clients' website.  I can access it from any machine except my development one.

If I ping it on my development machine, I get 80.67.28.107 - this is wrong.

My laptop, next to me, is able to resolve it correctly.

I have tried putting correct address into hosts like so:

93.187.232.191  www.superyoink.de

Still resolves to wrong address.

Rebooted, did ipconfig /flushdns  nothing seems to work.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: It might be better to post this on Server Fault - http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

A few things you could try:

- Double check your hosts file to make sure you don't have more than one entry for www.superyoink.de.  You may wish to include the content of your hosts file with your question.
- Compare the hosts file of your development machine and the laptop.  Assuming that the contents should be similar -- are there any significant differences with respect to www.superyoink.de?
- Compare the network configuration of your development machine and the laptop.  Are both machines using the same DNS servers or different DNS servers?

Comment: This example covers most of the possible causes.

In regards to the third suggestion, you should also check to see if you are doing any windows domain based name resolution. 

Finally, if you must, a packet trace could show you why PING is going to the wrong IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the DNS servers match a "working" machine?

Comment: Even when I entered bogus entries and can no longer access any site, the superyoink address resolves to that 80.67.28.107.  

Hosts file has 120.0.0.1 localhost now.

Comment: But are both host using the same DNS servers? It could be the case that one is pointing at an out-of-date/malicious DNS server